Верно ли написано? "Слышишь рокот? Грядет буря!"
Для шеврона будет использована данная фраза.
Можно ли так написать или после вопроса уточнить: "Это грядет буря!"

Для шеврона вообще не нужен вопрос, просто "Грядёт буря.". А вопросы должны задавать те, кто видит этот шеврон. Вопрос - это выражение сомнения. Или что-нибудь вроде: "слышен рокот / буря грядёт(в два ряда или по контуру)" - через утверждение. Кроме того никаких восклицательных знаков не нужно - выражение "грядёт буря" уже достаточно сильное утверждение, ему не нужна дополнительная экспрессия, которая наоборот ослабит эффект. Ну и вообще дизайн текста отдельная тема.

Абсолютно ненужная порча лаконичных предложений. Вставив "это", Вы разрушите ритм.
